# Weird "box" symbol appears when writing to a .txt file

Tags: java, save, fileoutputstream, bufferedwriter

I am trying to take a number value saved to a `.txt` file, convert it to an `int`, and then add this `int` and another one that is defined within the program. This section seems to be okay, however when I try to save this new value back to the original `.txt` file, a weird symbol is appearing.

```
/*
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public class TestForAqTablet1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int itemval=0;
        String  itemcount= "3";
        try{
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\kyleg\\Documents\\AQ App Storage\\stock\\1~ k\\od.txt" ));
            String line;
            System.out.println("reading file");
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                itemval = Integer.parseInt(line);
            }
            in.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestForAqTablet1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        //math
        System.out.println("previous number "+itemval);
        System.out.println("count "+itemcount);
        int total = itemval + Integer.parseInt(itemcount);
        System.out.println("Total: "+total);

        //write
        try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\kyleg\\Documents\\AQ App Storage\\stock\\1~ k\\od.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
            writer.write(total);
        catch (IOException ex) {
                // handle me
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `.txt` file it's reading from contains only the number `0`.

My goal is for this to increase every time the program is run, by the specified number (`itemcount`).

This is the error I keep getting:

```
run:
reading file
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
        at test.pkgfor.aq.tablet.pkg1.TestForAqTablet1.main(TestForAqTablet1.java:37)
C:\Users\kyleg\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: if you replace `writer.write(total);` with `writer.write("0");` are you still saving weird characters

Comment: when I change the code to that it is saving "0"

Comment: With the quotes or without the quotes

Comment: without it is just saving 0

Comment: okay, so now try to save your integer into a Integer (the object version) and then change the code I mentioned above to `writer.write(total.toString());`

Comment: @VGR posted the answer I was trying to communicate to you

Comment: it worked, thank you

Comment: See also:  "[How do I create a file and write to it in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173)" and _The Java Tutorials_: "[Reading, Writing, and Creating Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)".

Answer (score 2):

You are not writing a text file.  You are writing the bits of a `char` value.  From [the documentation of Writer.write(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write-int-):

> Writes a single character. The character to be written is contained in the 16 low-order bits of the given integer value; the 16 high-order bits are ignored.

If you want to write text using a Writer, you must convert your data to a String:

```
writer.write(String.valueOf(total));
```